# Libgdx-Select an actor on click then move it to an other position with second click

Tags: java, libgdx

I am coding a sort of Chess Game and I have a little problem.
In my game there are some Pawns on a Board and the Board is divided in 100 tiles.

What I just want to do is: When I click on a Pawn, it's selecting it and then when I click on an empty tile, the selected Pawn moves to this tile.

When I click on a Pawn, no problem I select it, but the problem occurs with the second click. I have an error: Null Pointer Exception. I don't know how to keep the selected Pawn in memory and then move it to new coordinates when I click a second time.

I use a gesture detector with a touchDown() method to listen if an Actor is clicked.

That's my code, it is the controller. I just put the interesting part with the clicked pawn:

```
    Actor cibletile = tiles[(int) Cx][(int) Cy]; //the clicked tile

    int tx = (int) cibletile.getX(); // pos x clicked tile
    int ty = (int) cibletile.getY(); // pos y clicked tile

    // if there is a Pawn on the tile
    if (pieces[tx][ty] != null) {
        System.out.println("there is a pawn here !");
        Piece piece = pieces[tx][ty];
        this.selectPiece(piece); //select the clicked pawn => this.plateau.PieceSelect

        } // there are no problems with this if condition all is working

    else{
         this.movePiece(this.plateau.PieceSelect,tx,ty); //move the selected Pawn to new coordonates when I click a second time


    } //the problem is here, I don't know how to move the Pawn after he is selected
```

I know that is not working because when I click on an Empty tile the IF condition is not ok and the this.plateau.PieceSelect is Null. This is why I have the Null Pointer Exception.

I really don't know how to do to select the Pawn and then move it when I click a second time, maybe another method?

I would be so happy if you can help me. I am on this problem since one week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really simple. Just convert your `else` clause into an `else if` and check if you have selected an `actor`.

```
else if(//Actor is selected i.e. some Actor object != null) {
    this.movePiece(this.plateau.PieceSelect,tx,ty);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer but I try it and it still not working. The problem is that each time I click the whole méthod (all the code that I put in thé first post) is call again. So if I click on a Pawn, ok the piece IS selected, but then when I click again on a empty tile the selectPiece doesnt exist anymore because I click on an empty tile so the IF condition is not OK there IS juste de else and the Null pointer exception happen.